# Use v-model in a v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, vue-material

I have a component with the following data -

```
data() {
    return {
        name: '',
        age: '',
    }
}
```

I then define a method like the following -

```
formData() {
   const data = [
      {label: 'Name', model: this.name},
      {label: 'Age', model: this.age},
   ]
   return data
}
```

In my template, I am writing a `v-for` loop accessing the `formData()` to render the HTML. (I'm doing it this way because there will be ~50 form fields like `name` and `age` and the HTML is the same for every form field).

```
<md-table>
    <md-table-row v-for="d in formData()" :key="d.label">
        <md-table-cell>{{d.label}}</md-table-cell>
        <md-table-cell>
            <md-field>
                 <md-input v-model="d.model"></md-input>
            </md-field>
        </md-table-cell>
    </md-table-row>
</md-table>
```

This template renders fine. However, the models are not bound, because the values of `name` and `age` does not change in the data if the user enters in the input fields.

I am pretty sure this is because when declaring `formData()`, I am actually passing the values of the data in the `model`. Is there a way I can actually pass the model, so that the template `v-models` bind?

Comment: If you assign the values of `name` and `age` to a new object you'll lose reactivity. Vue only adds reactivity to whatever you declare upfront, in data. Why wouldn't something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/qtg2zhf7/) work for your case? Please provide a [mcve], explaining in clear what you want to achieve. As in, the end goal, not the technical difficulties you're facing.

Comment: [Another variant](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/Lhxzq15e/) of the above. However, it loops through all properties of your items, so if your items have optional props, you'll actually have to specify which props you want to list in the table (otherwise you'll end up with rows having different number of `<td>`s, depending on the item's contents).

Comment: The relevant question here is: *"Why do you have `formData()`?* In what you've shown so far, its only purpose is to provide empty defaults to each element and break the reactivity you'd get if you looped directly through the item properties.

Answer (score -1):

Use props:

In the child component define:

```
props: ['name', 'age']
```

and remove the `data` element.